# os.path.exists is not working for particular directory

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, os.path

For example

```
 import os
filename = "C:\Windows\redir.txt"
if os.path.exists(filename):
    print ("Y")
else:
    print ("N")
```

`os.path.exists` doesn't work for this particular directory. Why? What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'\r'` represents Carriage Return. To use `\` as a backslash literally, you need to escape it:

```
filename = "C:\\Windows\\redir.txt"  # escape `\` s
```

or use raw string literal:

```
filename = r"C:\Windows\redir.txt"  # raw string literal
```

Answer (score 3):

`\r` is the carriage-return character. You need to escape it either by doubling the `\`:

```
filename = "C:\Windows\\redir.txt"
# Here ----------------^
```

or use a raw string by prefixing it with an `r`:

```
filename = r"C:\Windows\redir.txt"
# Here ----^
```